# Month function throwing type mismatch on example code from VBA help-file

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I checked here and all over the web and found a few solutions to this that I tried, including casting `Now` as a `CDate`, but nothing works.

Using the VBA Editor w/ Excel 2010 on Win7.

Even the example code from the help section is throwing this error and the date used in the `Month()` function is explicitely initialized in numeric form.

In both cases I tried using `CDate()` on the `month()` argument, it does not work. In my original code I also tried using `Date` instead of `Now`, no effect either.

Here is my original code, which casts the error on the If condition:

```vba
Function SetNextTaskNb()

    Dim seqNb As String
    seqNb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Persistent").Range("A" & 1).Value

    Dim Nbs() As String
    Nbs = Split(seqNb, ".", 2)

    Dim month, currentNb, nextNb As Integer    
    month = CInt(Nbs(0))
    currentNb = CInt(Nbs(1))

    If month(Now) = month Then 
        nextNb = currentNb + 1
    Else
        nextNb = 1
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Persistent").Range("A" & 1).Value = currentMonth + "." + nextNb
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & 1).Value = currentMonth + "." + nextNb

End Function
```

Here is the example code from the VBA Editor Help section, which, copy-pasted with no modifications throws the same error on the first `Debug.Print`. It won't even display it.

```vba
Dim MyDate, MyMonth
MyDate = #2/12/1969#            ' Assign a date.
Debug.Print "month is " & month(MyDate)
Debug.Print "rgMonth.Cells(i, j).Value is " & rgMonth.Cells(i, j).Value
MyMonth = month(CDate(MyDate))    ' MyMonth contains 2.
```

I know I'm supposed to give the Month() function a date in numeric form, and that it returns an Integer. I tried everything I could think of.

Here is proof this is the code from the Help:

[image: Type Mismatch on example code]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are using **Month** as both the name of a function and the name of a variable................give the variable a different name.

Comment: Right on. Don't use function or any reserved names as variables, it's a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Thank you! Did I mention I'm very new to VBA? I feel stupid right now.

Comment: Don't feel stupid......just like **C** or **C++** , **VBA** has its own little traps!